# Rails ERROR: 'missing FROM-clause entry' when order through associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails 5 and Ruby 2.4 app I've got two models `CaregiverAuthorization` and `Registrant`:

```
# caregiver_authorization
class CaregiverAuthorization < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :registrant

  scope :pending, (-> { where(status: [statuses[:pending], statuses[:pending_renewal]]) })
end

# registrant
class Registrant < User
  has_many :caregiver_authorizations,
           (-> { order('created_at asc') })

  def full_name
    [first_name, last_name].join(' ')
  end
end
```

Now I want to have all pending `caregiver_authorizations` ordered by `registrant.full_name`. Pretty simple, so I did:

`CaregiverAuthorization.includes(:registrant).order("registrants.full_name")`

Surprisingly I got below error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "registrants"
LINE 1: ...id" AND "users"."type" IN ('Registrant') ORDER BY registrant...
                                                             ^
```

What did I missed?

**[Edit]**

Full error message:

```
  SQL (0.8ms)  SELECT "caregiver_authorizations"."id" AS t0_r0, "caregiver_authorizations"."registrant_id" AS t0_r1, "caregiver_authorizations"."reviewer_id" AS t0_r2, "caregiver_authorizations"."reviewed_at" AS t0_r3, "caregiver_authorizations"."status" AS t0_r4, "caregiver_authorizations"."created_at" AS t0_r5, "caregiver_authorizations"."updated_at" AS t0_r6, "users"."id" AS t1_r0, "users"."external_system_id" AS t1_r1, "users"."external_system_type" AS t1_r2, "users"."type" AS t1_r3, "users"."login_id" AS t1_r4, "users"."first_name" AS t1_r5, "users"."last_name" AS t1_r6, "users"."status" AS t1_r7, "users"."minor" AS t1_r8, "users"."created_at" AS t1_r9, "users"."updated_at" AS t1_r10, "users"."paper_entry" AS t1_r11, "users"."date_of_birth" AS t1_r12, "users"."caregiver_limit_override" AS t1_r13, "users"."patient_limit_override" AS t1_r14 FROM "caregiver_authorizations" LEFT OUTER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "caregiver_authorizations"."registrant_id" AND "users"."type" IN ('Registrant') ORDER BY registrants.full_name
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "registrants"
LINE 1: ...id" AND "users"."type" IN ('Registrant') ORDER BY registrant...
                                                             ^
: SELECT "caregiver_authorizations"."id" AS t0_r0, "caregiver_authorizations"."registrant_id" AS t0_r1, "caregiver_authorizations"."reviewer_id" AS t0_r2, "caregiver_authorizations"."reviewed_at" AS t0_r3, "caregiver_authorizations"."status" AS t0_r4, "caregiver_authorizations"."created_at" AS t0_r5, "caregiver_authorizations"."updated_at" AS t0_r6, "users"."id" AS t1_r0, "users"."external_system_id" AS t1_r1, "users"."external_system_type" AS t1_r2, "users"."type" AS t1_r3, "users"."login_id" AS t1_r4, "users"."first_name" AS t1_r5, "users"."last_name" AS t1_r6, "users"."status" AS t1_r7, "users"."minor" AS t1_r8, "users"."created_at" AS t1_r9, "users"."updated_at" AS t1_r10, "users"."paper_entry" AS t1_r11, "users"."date_of_birth" AS t1_r12, "users"."caregiver_limit_override" AS t1_r13, "users"."patient_limit_override" AS t1_r14 FROM "caregiver_authorizations" LEFT OUTER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "caregiver_authorizations"."registrant_id" AND "users"."type" IN ('Registrant') ORDER BY registrants.full_name
```

Maybe this will be helpfully:

```
2.4.5 :065 > CaregiverAuthorization.includes(:registrant).order("registrants.full_name").to_sql
 => "SELECT \"caregiver_authorizations\".\"id\" AS t0_r0, \"caregiver_authorizations\".\"registrant_id\" AS t0_r1, \"caregiver_authorizations\".\"reviewer_id\" AS t0_r2, \"caregiver_authorizations\".\"reviewed_at\" AS t0_r3, \"caregiver_authorizations\".\"status\" AS t0_r4, \"caregiver_authorizations\".\"created_at\" AS t0_r5, \"caregiver_authorizations\".\"updated_at\" AS t0_r6, \"users\".\"id\" AS t1_r0, \"users\".\"external_system_id\" AS t1_r1, \"users\".\"external_system_type\" AS t1_r2, \"users\".\"type\" AS t1_r3, \"users\".\"login_id\" AS t1_r4, \"users\".\"first_name\" AS t1_r5, \"users\".\"last_name\" AS t1_r6, \"users\".\"status\" AS t1_r7, \"users\".\"minor\" AS t1_r8, \"users\".\"created_at\" AS t1_r9, \"users\".\"updated_at\" AS t1_r10, \"users\".\"paper_entry\" AS t1_r11, \"users\".\"date_of_birth\" AS t1_r12, \"users\".\"caregiver_limit_override\" AS t1_r13, \"users\".\"patient_limit_override\" AS t1_r14 FROM \"caregiver_authorizations\" LEFT OUTER JOIN \"users\" ON \"users\".\"id\" = \"caregiver_authorizations\".\"registrant_id\" AND \"users\".\"type\" IN ('Registrant') ORDER BY registrants.full_name"
```

Comment: Can you please post the full error message including the full stack trace and the SQL query generated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please note that `includes` does not necessarily join tables in the database query. It is built to avoid N+1 queries and it might happen that it simply runs two queries (one for the `caregiver_authorizations` and another for the associated `registrants`.

When you really need both tables in one query because you need to filter or order by them then you need to use `joins`. Additionally, the table is not named `registrants` but `users` because `Registrant` is a subclass of `User`. And you cannot order by `full_name` because `full_name` is not a database query but a method in your model. To order by `full_name` you need to simulate the behavior of that method in SQL.

I guess the following should work for you:

```
CaregiverAuthorization
  .pending
  .joins(:registrant)
  .order(Arel.sql("LOWER(CONCAT(users.first_name, ' ', users.last_name))"))
```

Comment: It produces the same error than my: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "registrants"`

Comment: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column users.full_name does not exist`. If I replace `users.full_name` by `user.first_name` the error disappear but it does not return it in the desired order: `CaregiverAuthorization.pending.joins(:registrant).order('users.first_name').map { |auth| auth.registrant.first_name }` will produce me `=> ["EEEEeFFFFgggHH", "aaaaaaa test", "bbbBBBbb", "caregiver testing"]`

Comment: @mr_muscle`full_name` is not a column in your database, it is a method in your model. So you cannot use it when querying the database. Also ordering is case sensitive (which is why `E` is being returned before `a`), so you probably should use `order(Arel.sql('lower(users.first_name)'))` if you want it to be case insensitive

Comment: If you do actually want to use the first name to order users you would use `order("CONCAT( users.first_name, ' ',  users.last_name")`. Some required reading though https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: @spickermann your code produce syntax error. Please update to: `CaregiverAuthorization.pending.joins(:registrant).order(Arel.sql("LOWER(CONCAT(users.first_name,' ', users.last_name))"))`

Comment: @mr_muscle fixed